# Prompt <20 rep user when trying to join a gallery room

Tags: bug, chat

I am not a room owner (yet) but I belong to [the greatest SO chat room ever](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) and, as so, the owners get a lot of pings from users wanting to join. Many whom don't realize or understand that they don't have enough rep to join even *if* the owners wanted to allow them.

This seems to add to the already busy schedule of the owners. It seems like a fairly easy-to-implement solution would be to check if the users have enough rep to even join a chat when they press the button to get access. Then the system could notify the user that they don't have enough rep and they can go get them some and come back.

Just a simple pop up with something like "You need 20 rep to join a chat room and you currently have 'X'". Then the owners don't need to be notified and the user doesn't have to be rejected (with the exception of the pop up rejection message).

**Reproduced by your truly**

I *am now* a room owner of previously mentioned greatest SO chat room ever and I see these requests come through quite often from <20 rep users. Not a huge deal but definitely annoying and a bug which is why I have retagged.

I have also created a testing account and kept it under 20 but haven't been able to request access with that guy.

Comment: That almost seems like a bug really.

Comment: @TravisJ Possibly but I would think more of something that just wasn't thought to implement. Because they still have read access to chats.

Comment: @TravisJ A bug is a feature not working as it's designed; if it wasn't designed at all it isn't a bug.